# How to import a method from an external package in Golang?

Tags: go, methods, struct, import

Sorry if this question is a bit basic however I have not been able to find any documentation on it.
I am trying to **import** the following method from `example.com/User/project/controllers` package

```
func (env *Env) Index(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx, ps fasthttprouter.Params){
   fmt.Fprintf(ctx, "Hi there! RequestURI is %q", ctx.RequestURI())
}
```

Into the following file to be used in a router as follows

```
db, err := db.Conn()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    env := &Env{db}

    ...

   router.GET("/", env.controllers.Index)///this import is not valid
```

I have tried to use `controllers.env.Index` `env.controllers.Index` I have also tried importing with a `.` before the import .etc
How would one in this instance import a method from another package whereby a struct (`ENV`) can be passed to it? To clarify the problem here is using method on top of the package ontop of the helper e.g. `method.package.helper` how would I resolve the above code so that I can pass a method to a helper from an external package
Thanks

Comment: Have you read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), which covers this specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you would like to pass in your db struct to your Env struct correct?

[This](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/2) may help if I am understanding correctly.

Since a struct is really just a collection of fields, it's dependent on the makeup of the Env struct.

What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have revised my question. the problem I am experiencing here is that I can no longer use `method.helper` in an external package I need to somehow reference the package from which the method was derived.Thus provided `method.(external)package.helper` is not functional: what would be a successful approach in order to import a method from another package to which a struct can be applied? Thanks again

Comment: If you're looking to import a method from another package, that function needs to be 'exported.' Which means that the function must not be a method(tied to an object) and that function must also be capitalized at the beginning like so:

`func Something() {
     fmt.Println("hey!")
}`

EDIT: sorry, didn't realize SO automatically posts comments on return